# CNAME alias gets truncated in Google Domains

Tags: dns, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to follow the steps on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website to host a static website on Google Cloud Storage. The domain, "peek.solutions", I bought on Google Domains.

I'm at the "Creating a CNAME alias" part. On the Google Domains Registrar, in "DNS settings" and "Custom resource records", I added one with the NAME "www.peek.solutions". However, I noticed that after I click "Add" the NAME gets truncated to "www":

[image]

Also when I try to change it to "www.peek.solutions" with the "Edit" button, like so,

[image]

After clicking "Save" I still get the same truncated "www" name.

The problem with this is that according to the instructions, I'm supposed to create a Bucket with a name that matches the CNAME I created for my domain. If I try to fill in "www" in the "Name" field, I get "The bucket is already in use":

[image]

Why is Google Domains truncating the "NAME" field when defining a CNAME alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the bucket with the full name, so www.peek.solutions.
You've had to show you own the domain so you should be able to create this bucket.

Buckets namespace is fully global. So if someone in the entire world had the idea to name his/her bucket 'www', this means it's not available for every other person on the planet. Other naming requirements are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming), but you should just name it www.peek.solutions

In [this](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251147?hl=en) documentation under CNAME, google seems to only display www as well.
I suppose it's the right way of doing it, just not an intuitive way of displaying it by Google.
Either way you can still modify the CNAME setup once you've created the bucket, so just create it and see if it works!

Comment: I actually tried to just create the bucket with `www.peek.solutions` as its name. However, after uploading the files and making them public, [www.peek.solutions](www.peek.solutions) shows "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it." I'm not sure, however, whether it is because of the bucket name or some other issue.

Comment: The website seems to work for me! What was the issue you had with the xml?